# Where are shared preferences stored?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Where in an Eclipse project might one encounter a shared preferences file?

Comment: I am aware that shared preference.xml is stored in data, but where is it stored before being installed; in .smali format?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

SharedPreferences are stored in an xml file in the app data folder, i.e.

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
```

or the default preferences at:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
```

SharedPreferences added during runtime are not stored in the Eclipse project.

Note: Accessing `/data/data/<package_name>` requires superuser privileges

Comment: The default shared preferences file would actually be: `/data/data/<package>/shared_prefs/<package>_preferences.xml`.

Comment: @inazaruk It is indeed the full package name, although I see mixed uses of `/<package>_preferences.xml` and `/<package>.xml` on devices. Perhaps it depends on the API level of the app?

Comment: Note that I was taking about *Default* shared preferences. It looks like filename was always the same for them. See initial commit for `PreferenceManager.java`, `getDefaultSharedPreferences` function here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java;hb=54b6cfa9a9e5b861a9930af873580d6dc20f773c#l351. And it wasn't changed in the latest version of `PrefencesManager.jave` too: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java;hb=HEAD#l353

Comment: Any way to get the path from system, and not hard-code it? ContextImpl.java implements it in private getPreferencesDir func, it would be useful to get this at runtime somehow.

Comment: You can use new FIle(context.getFilesDir().getParent(), "shared_prefs"). It does work on Nexus 5, not sure about other manufactures.

Comment: The app makes these codes are working without rooting phone, but you should see the files on the directory of phone:../data/data folder with only rooting your Android device, but you kill the phone's warranty if you root your phone for checking the data files.

Answer (score 9):

Preferences can either be set in code or can be found in res/xml/preferences.xml. You can read more about preferences on the Android SDK website.

Comment: You have to create it - as long as you have created an Android project, you can then right click on the "res" directory and add a new folder called 'xml'. Other "special" folders are anim, drawable, layout, menu, raw, and values.

Answer (score 7):

I just tried to get path of shared preferences below like this.This is work for me.

```
File f = getDatabasePath("MyPrefsFile.xml");

if (f != null)
    Log.i("TAG", f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to save some of you time...

On my Galaxy S v.2.3.3 Shared Preferences are not stored in:`/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`

but are now located in: `/dbdata/databases/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`

I believe they changed this in 2.3

Comment: Is it same in 2.2? I cant find /data file anywhere in my project either in eclipse or project location.

Comment: @pramod not in eclipse - this is the path on the actual device file structure.

Comment: @Pramod see it in file explorer view and  there in `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`

Comment: `/dbdata/` does not exists on my JB device

Answer (score 5):

The data is stored on the device, in your application's private data area.  It is not in an Eclipse project.

Answer (score 5):

Shared Preferences are the key/value pairs that we can store. They are internal type of storage which means we do not have to create an external database to store it. To see it go to,
 1) Go to View in the menu bar. Select Tool Windows.
 2) Click on Device File Explorer.
 3) Device File Explorer opens up in the right hand side.
 4) Find the data folder and click on it.
 5) In the data folder, you can select another data folder.
 6) Try to search for your package name in this data folder. Ex: com.example.com
 7) Then Click on shared_prefs and open the .xml file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use  http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ library to access your app's local storage with chrome inspect tools.
You can find sharedPreference file under Local storage -> < your app's package name >

[image]

Answer (score 1):

save in **/data/data/your_package_name/shared_prefs/**

For see that you can use:

**[Android Device Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392716/4797289)**

**[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)**

**[Android Debug Database](http://**%5BAndroid%20Device%20Monitor%5D%5B2%5D**)**