# android sharedpreferences does not save data when app restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `sharedpreference` which save data fine until the app close. when app restart the data in `sharedpreferences` was gone please tell me the solution. I want when app close or restart or phone restart my data in `preferences` was saved.

```
public static final String MyPREF_MOB = "MyPref_mob";
public static final String WALLPAPER_MOB = "wallpaper_mob";

if(encodedImagee!=null) {
    // shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre1.edit();
    edit.putString(WALLPAPER_MOB, encodedImagee);
    edit.apply();
    //  Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "new same image in prefrences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
shre1 = getSharedPreferences(MyPREF_MOB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final String image_save =shre1.getString(WALLPAPER_MOB, "");
```

i have also try this

```
 if(encodedImagee!=null)
        {
           // shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre1.edit();
            edit.putString("mob_wallpaper", encodedImagee);
            edit.commit();
            //  Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "new same image in prefrences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final String image_save =shre1.getString("mob_wallpaper", "");
```

i have use this code data save when app restart also i can get data but when phone restart data again gone

```
if(encodedImagee!=null)
        {
           // shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre1.edit();
            edit.remove("mob_wallpaper");
            edit.apply();
            edit.putString("mob_wallpaper", encodedImagee);
            edit.apply();
            //  Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "new same image in prefrences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final String image_save =shre1.getString("mob_wallpaper", "");
```

Comment: please provide more information about when you save data and when you retrieve it again during the aplication's lifecycle.. and how

Comment: i have a loop in which i used sharedprefrences to get data and save and retrieve it its work fine but when app close data in sharedprefences gone

Comment: please provide some more code

Comment: @AbhishekPatel which type of code?

Comment: the code showing where exactly do you do your save/query the data

Comment: as per your already posted code your prederence code flow couldn't understand properly

Comment: What is encoded Image

Comment: encoded is string base64

Comment: @yogi it is string base64

Comment: i have update question i have one solution but its not working when phone restart but its work when app restart

Answer (score 2):

**Try this,**

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (encodedImagee != null){
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putString("mob_wallpaper", encodedImagee);
            edit.commit();
        }else{
            final String image_save = sharedPreferences.getString("mob_wallpaper","");
            // put your logic over here
        }
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` cleared data only when app data clear and at the time of uninstall.

Comment: SharedPreferences shre1;

Comment: object of sharedprefrence how?

Comment: Try updated code. Also post logic for `encodedImagee`

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your sample code that you use

- `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` for reading
- `getSharedPreferences(MyPREF_MOB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` for writing

I think you should use the same in both cases.

Try to replace

```
shre1 = getSharedPreferences(MyPREF_MOB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

by

```
shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: its working fine save data and retrieve data but when app restart data gone

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the preference instance with this
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
// acccess a saved key value
mPrefs.getString("key", "default_value");
//save a key-value
mPrefs.edit().putString("key", "new_value").apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your code in this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(.....){
    super.onCreate(......);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml);
shre1 = getSharedPreferences(MyPREF_MOB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

final String image_save =shre1.getString(WALLPAPER_MOB, "");
```

and when you want to update your image

```
if(encodedImagee!=null) {
// shre1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre1.edit();
edit.putString(WALLPAPER_MOB, encodedImagee);
edit.commit(); //make use of commit
//  Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "new same image in prefrences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: would you mind updating your question with more detail.
i was able to make out only this by the snippet you have provided

Comment: i have update question i have one solution but its not working when phone restart but its work when app restart

Comment: why you are loading pref again and again?

Comment: because i want to get current wallpaper looper save current wallpaper again and again

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted