# change language programmatically not working after app force close

Tags: android, xml, configuration, sdk, localization

when my app get crashed for any reason or force close i hit OK `button` on the message says "`unfortunately the app has been stopped`" . then my app is come back again to same `activity` , but it get it in other Language set and call `OnResume()`

my Question is how to make my app return to same `Language config` even when my app has been crashed for some reason.

I'm trying to refresh and get the last config was set in `sharedPreferences` and refresh my config or content view but no luck

Code :

```
 @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if(appSharedPrefs.getBoolean("IsArabic",true)){
        Log.d("ERRRRR", "AR"); // that is called 
        setLocale(getApplicationContext(), "ar");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("ERRRRR", "EN");
        setLocale(getApplicationContext(), "en");
    }
}

protected  void setLocale(final Context ctx, final String lang)
{
    Log.d("ERRRRR", lang);

  /*  final Locale loc = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(loc);
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setLocale(loc);
    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);*/




    Resources res = ctx.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(lang.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d("ERRRRR", "onConfigurationChanged");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

you can catch the crash event and load your `activity` with your desired `locale` and `configuration`...

use this utility class:

```
 public class ExceptionHandler implements
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Activity myContext;


    public ExceptionHandler(Activity context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

        //you can show a dialog here telling that something went wrong
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, your_activity.class); //start your activity
        //put your locale you can use shared preference also
        intent.putExtra("locale", "ar");
        myContext.startActivity(intent);

        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);
    }
}
```

Now use it in your `Mainactivity` `onCreate` like

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
```

Comment: my problem is not in SharedPreferences  , it works for me , but after getting the right Lang , the layout still working in other Lang after my app is crashed

Comment: after the app got crashed ...shared preferences loses it's value so your `appSharedPrefs.getBoolean` gives you wrong value

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted

Comment: i have tested it without getting from SharedPreferences , make it arabic Lang in both values , but still get wrong layout LTR

Comment: i used this code :         Resources res = myContext.getResources();
        // Change locale settings in the app.
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale("ar");
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

Comment: but no effect is was taken after this code runs out

Comment: after your app got crashed you activity is restarted and onResume called..it then loads language form `sharedpreferences`?

Comment: Yes , i have tested from sharedpreferences and without sharedpreferences , I used it to force to load arabic but not effect is taken , my layout still in English state from left to right , it should be on arabic from right to left as i want

Comment: it's load the english xml layout insted of arabic xml layout , how to force it to load arabic xml layout only when activity restart ?

Comment: you mean when the app got crashed?

Comment: thank you , but i was tested your same code , but it also getting the wrong layout English left to right