# Shared Preferences reset data when app crashed. Please guide

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sharedpreferences

My app got crashed and all the data in **shared preference** got cleared.
I am saving some flags and maintaining user session in shared preference.
One of the flag is **IsFirstLaunch**, which tells me whether app is launching for first time or not, if returns true then I am downloading some data from server and storing in **SQLite database**.

Please guide, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code where app is crashing and error log too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted

Comment: share log cat info or code to find reason for crash.

Comment: @DkThakur : sad part is I have not been able to regenerate same scenario again, i tried a lot for it, so don't have error log.

Comment: Then how we can identify where you are doing things wrong or where is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after the crash when it went to load the Preferences there was a **blank in the preferences xml** file which caused the preferences to reset.

To avoid this you could put all preference modifications in **synchronized blocks or even use one synchronized static method for all preference writing**.

I think - you need a better way of managing and storing the data you're saving.

The next time the shared preferences were accessed however, the xml file was cleared and started new.

for example :

```
private static final class SharedPreferencesImpl implements SharedPreferences {
...
    public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
        synchronized (this) {
            String v = (String)mMap.get(key);
            return v != null ? v : defValue;
        }
   }
...
    public final class EditorImpl implements Editor {
        public Editor putString(String key, String value) {
            synchronized (this) {
                mModified.put(key, value);
                return this;
            }
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...can you please give me some piece of code for the same?

Comment: Yes..
Thank You So Much