# What issues are there with keeping SharedPreferences open?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've created [DroidPrefs](https://github.com/bradley-curran/DroidPrefs), a library that serialises and deserialises Java objects to `SharedPreferences`.

You save objects like so:

```
Animal newAnimal = new Animal("Gitty", "Octocat", 8);
DroidPrefs.instance(context).put("animal", newAnimal).apply();
```

Every time `DroidPrefs.instance(Context)` is called, I am doing the following:

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

My question is, does `SharedPreferences` work like a file? Should I only open it when reading and writing, or can I open it at the start of the app and not worry about other parts of the code accessing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences stores data in a XML file[You may be interested to see [Where are shared preferences stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146207/321272) too ], hence work like a file indeed. It is optimized way to store and retrieve primitive data in Android compared to File IO.

Coming to your second question on accessing shared preference:
   It is always better to open when u need it and close it when you don't. However, you may go for singleton class(may be a factory pattern in case of multiple shared preferences) which manages access to SharedPreferences to have a neat design.