# Where are the data stored or saved from the SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know the **SharedPreferences** are interface for accessing and modifying data returned by the `getSharedPreferences()` method. We can **fetch**, **edit** or **delete** these data, but where are these data stored? In some sort of database, or it is just an object in memory?

Comment: Duplicate?: [Where are shared preferences stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146106/456814).

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` are stored in an .xml file. It is stored in your applications installation folder.

For more information, check out the doc: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)