# How to inspect an Android-app on device (tablet)?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms (cross-platform-development for iOS, Android an WP).
With the latest version, it is possible to store properties persistent.
This works for iOS and WP, but it seems that there are problems on Android.
Unfortunately, the Xamarin-documentation is more than poor...
As the properties are stored persistent, they have to be stored on the device (I think in a File to the app).
For iOS, there is a tool named IExplore (not Internet Explorer;-). With this tool, I am able to inspect the App on the device (iPhone) and also can see the file with the settings.
**Questions:**
 **- I think, such persistent properties should stored in an file to the
   app (like in iOS) -> Correct?**
 **- Is there a tool (like iExplore for iOS) to inspect an installed App
   on a device (e.g. Samsung T900 tablet)?**

**Thanks for any feedback**

Update:
According to:   [Where are shared preferences stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored) , the data should be stored under /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
In Visual Studio (+ Xamarin), I have a tool "Android Device Monitor".
With this tool, I can access the file-system of the tablet.
If I do that, I can see a /data/ folder, but no sub-directories and also no folder to my app...

Comment: I don't think you can see such data if using a physical device (unless rooted) for debugging. Use an emulator and see if you can locate the files. Also make sure your settings are being saved, otherwise the OS will not generate any preference file.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

- App settings in Android may be stored in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It's design is ideal for this
- It's called **[DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)** for android, but I'm not sure if xamarin has integrated it in its IDE