# Cannot read BuildConfig.variable in Android Java app

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've ran into some issues with reading variables to and from the build.gradle(:app):.

I asked a question how to fix so that gradle recognizes the apikey.properties file I have added to root, and gradle does not complain any more.

Here's my old question: [Gradle build won't find the apikey.properties file in root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661700/gradle-build-wont-find-the-apikey-properties-file-in-root-folder)

But I cannot read the values in my Java app code, the BuildConfig.SCOPE and what not is coming back "null".

My
**build.gradle(:app):**

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
if (rootProject.file("apikey.properties").exists()) {
    properties.load(rootProject.file("apikey.properties").newDataInputStream())
}
def scope = properties.getProperty("SCOPE")
def client_Id = properties.getProperty("CLIENT_ID")
def client_Secret = properties.getProperty("CLIENT_SECRET")
def grant_Type = properties.getProperty("GRANT_TYPE")


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my_fantastic_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.3"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // should correspond to key/value pairs inside the file
        buildConfigField("String", "SCOPE", "\"$scope\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"$client_Id\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "CLIENT_SECRET", "\"$client_Secret\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "GRANT_TYPE", "\"$grant_Type\"")

    }

...
println("scope: " + scope)
println("client_Id: " + client_Id)
println("client_Secret: " + client_Secret)
println("grant_Type: " + grant_Type)
...
```

**apikey.properties file:**

```
SCOPE=xxx
CLIENT_yyy
CLIENT_zzz
GRANT_TYPE=client_credentiaals
```

When I try to println from the build.gradle, I get result:
scope: null
client_Id: null
client_Secret: null
grant_Type: null

When I debug a **random java.class:**

```
        String scope = BuildConfig.SCOPE;
        String clientId = BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID;
        String clientSecret = BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET;
        String grantType = BuildConfig.GRANT_TYPE;


        System.out.println("Scope: " + scope);
        System.out.println("clientId: " + clientId);
        System.out.println("clientSecret: " + clientSecret);
        System.out.println("grantType: " + grantType);
```

I get this:
[image]

Any suggestions? Should I redesign the whole handling of variables in gradle? Any suggestion how to do this so I can handle both local and DevOps pipeline/variables? Big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the path to the apikey.properties file in **build.gradle(:app):**

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
if (rootProject.file("app/apikey.properties").exists()) {
    properties.load(rootProject.file("app/apikey.properties").newDataInputStream())
```