# Can Android's SharedPrefs File be converted to a Binary Blob and then back again?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Hi I am currently working on a small app and I was working with the sharedprefs file for android.

My question is, is it possible to convert the SharedPrefs file to a binary blob to then be sent as a snapshot using google play's save game service?

**I don't want any code I was just wondering if it was at all possible.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. You can read the SharedPreferences storage file directly (See [here for the location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored)) as a binary file.

Comment: @JonasCz Hmm Interesting I'll have a look into it thanks :)