# How to restore Android Sharedpreferences from XML file after making its backup in sd card?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences, database-backups, android-sharedpreferences

I have searched for this but i didn't get an answer.
I am working on Budget app and in that there are two type of databases(Sqlite and Shared-preferences). As i can BACKUP/RESTORE of sqlite database in sdcard but I don't know how to backup and restore shared preferences database.

I am able to backup shared-preferences database but don't know how to restore it from sd card.
Databases names:
1.magicbox_database.db is sqlite database,
2.magicbox_database_sf.db is sharedpreferences database

This is a code for Backup for both database.

```
if (isStoragePermissionGranted() == true) {
                    try {
                        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        if (sd.canWrite()) {
                            String currentDBPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/OLBE_DEMO";
                            String backupDBPath = "magicbox_database.db";
                            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "backup creating....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                                src.close();
                                dst.close();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bckup Created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "magicbox_database.db  in External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                            String currentDBPath1 = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs/DATABASE.xml";
                            String backupDBPath1 = "magicbox_database_sf.xml";
                            File currentDB1 = new File(currentDBPath1);
                            File backupDB1 = new File(sd, backupDBPath1);
                           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "backup creating....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (currentDB1.exists()) {
                                FileChannel src1 = new FileInputStream(currentDB1).getChannel();
                                FileChannel dst1 = new FileOutputStream(backupDB1).getChannel();
                                dst1.transferFrom(src1, 0, src1.size());
                                src1.close();
                                dst1.close();
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bckup Created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "magicbox_database_sf.db  in External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR! backup not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

This code for Restore for both

```
 if (isStoragePermissionGranted() == true) {
                    try {
                        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        if (sd.canWrite()) {
                            String currentDBPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/OLBE_DEMO";
                            String backupDBPath = "magicbox_database.db";
                            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "restoring......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                                src.close();
                                dst.close();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your data Restored !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            String currentDBPath1 = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs/DATABASE.xml";
                            String backupDBPath1 = "magicbox_database_sf.xml";
                            File currentDB1 = new File(currentDBPath1);
                            File backupDB1 = new File(sd, backupDBPath1);
                            if (currentDB1.exists()) {
                                FileChannel src1 = new FileInputStream(backupDB1).getChannel();
                                FileChannel dst1 = new FileOutputStream(currentDB1).getChannel();
                                dst1.transferFrom(src1, 0, src1.size());
                                src1.close();
                                dst1.close();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "magicbox_database_sf.db  in External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR! data not restored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

changes are in this code

```
 FileChannel src1 = new FileInputStream(backupDB1).getChannel();
 FileChannel dst1 = new FileOutputStream(currentDB1).getChannel();
```

Comment: magicbox_database_sf.db is sharedpreferences database - what does this mean ?

Comment: Shared Pref are key value pairs !!!

Comment: @shadygoneinsane  magic_database_sf.db is name of the database which i am saving in SDCARD

Comment: So you want to restore dql Db not Sharedpreferences ?
please b clear while asking any question as to what you want to achieve !!

Comment: @shadygoneinsane NO i want to backup and restore Sharedprefrences database.

Comment: Ok i got what you want

Comment: Not able to find SharedPref at location - 
"/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs/DATABASE.xml"

Comment: DATABASE.xml is sharedprefrence database in my android database.    and magicbox_database_sf.xml is named after it after backup.

Comment: Check updated answer.. this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146207/5134647) to get the path and XML file can be easily extracted with all your preferences - then you can use this xml content(By parsing it) to create Preferences or extract values

XML will look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="Key2" value="100" />
    <long name="Key1" value="99" />
    <string name="Key">Vikesh Dass</string>
</map>
```

Just parse the xml to get your Data this should be easy :)

For Parsing Xml you can use this class:

```
public class XMLParser {

private static final String ns = null;

public void parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        readPreferences(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private void readPreferences(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "map");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String node = parser.getName();
        if (node.equals("string")) {
            readName(parser);
        } else if (node.equals("int")) {
            readValueint(parser);
        } else if (node.equals("long")) {
            readValuelong(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
}

private void readName(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "string");
    String name = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "string");
    //Set the Preference again after it is fetched
}

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

private void readValueint(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "int");
    String ValueData = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
    String ValueKey = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
    //Set the Preference again after it is fetched
}

private void readValuelong(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "long");
    String ValueData = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
    String ValueKey = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
    //Set the Preference again after it is fetched
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

And from your class call this:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String backupDBPath1 = "your_backedUpPrefDb.xml";
        File backupDB1 = new File(sd, backupDBPath1);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(backupDB1));
        XMLParser myXMLParser = new XMLParser();
        myXMLParser.parse(is);
        is.close();
```

Comment: i can backup shareprefrences database and i am getting magicbox_database_sf.xml file but now i want to restore it.                                  How can i restore?

Comment: Did you meant you want to create those Preferences again ?

Comment: hey. i have a app in which there is sharedprefrence database and in that there are some values now i will uninstall my app then data will be delete so i need database backup which i have alredy done. now i need to restore that sharedprefrence database.

Comment: Then you will have to read the xml which you have backed up .. then parse the elements to get all the values (e.g from above xml: Key2 - 100 which is int and Key - Vikesh Dass which is String and likewise and with these values again create your sharedprefrence database.
Thats all i know Hope this helps :)

Comment: i ddnt implement it, but it can be a answer..  and Thanks