# Retrieve Xamarin secured storage data from native Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, xamarin.android, android-storage

I have an application written in Xamarin that saves data using SecureStorage.SetAsync. Now I need to convert the application into native Kotlin and Swift projects. Xamarin stores the data in the iOS keychain which is relatively simple to retrieve. However I am struggling to retrieve the data in Kotlin Android as I believe I need to find the key and decrypt the data manually.

How do I go about retrieving the data in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document about the [Platform Implementation Specifics of the SecureStorage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android#platform-implementation-specifics), it used the android native api Shared Preferences to store the data.

> The Android KeyStore is used to store the cipher key used to encrypt the value before it is saved into a Shared Preferences with a filename of [YOUR-APP-PACKAGE-ID].xamarinessentials. The key (not a cryptographic key, the key to the value) used in the shared preferences file is a MD5 Hash of the key passed into the SecureStorage APIs.

So I have tried this `SecureStorage.SetAsync("test", "hahaha");`. Then I searched about the [android default location of the shared preferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146207/17455524), it is in the `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.xamarinessentials.xml`.

I checked the file with the Android Studio's Device File Explorer:

[image]

The value has been encrypted, you can check the [source code about encrypting the string](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/SecureStorage/SecureStorage.android.cs#L77). In addition, you can check the source code about how did it use the shared preferences [`var sharedPreferences = GetSharedPreferences(sharedName)`](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Preferences/Preferences.android.cs#L28). And the sharedName is the [`string Alias = $"{AppInfo.PackageName}.xamarinessentials"` in the SecureStorage class](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/35c56205769b1434838ad31ff9c65d5d0c3f50d5/Xamarin.Essentials/SecureStorage/SecureStorage.shared.cs#L9).

So I used the android native api to read the shared preferences file:

```
var name = this.PackageName + ".xamarinessentials";
var sp = GetSharedPreferences(name, FileCreationMode.Private);
var value = sp.GetString("test",null);
```

And the debug result:

[image]

The value is encrypted and you need to decrypt it according to the source code about encrypting the string. So you can just convert the three line c# code to kotlin code to get the value.

In addition, if you want to convert the xamarin app to Android Kotlin app, you can use the [native SharedPreferences api](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) directly. I can't understand why you need to **Retrieve Xamarin secured storage data from native Kotlin Android**.

Comment: My question title could perhaps be worded better, but your answer it perfectly regardless! I will go away and write the Kotlin code in full and report back. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, and I'm looking forward to your reply. @FriedRice

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Liyun Zhang - MSFT's answer, here is the Kotlin code:

```
fun decryptPrefData(preferenceKey: String): String? {
    val alias = "${context.packageName}.xamarinessentials"
    val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(alias, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return sharedPref.getString(preferenceKey, null)?.let { encryptedFullString ->
        val encryptedFullBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedFullString, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val iv = encryptedFullBytes.copyOfRange(0, 12)
        val encryptedData = encryptedFullBytes.copyOfRange(12, encryptedFullBytes.size)

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)
        val secretKey = keyStore.getKey(alias, null) as SecretKey

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, GCMParameterSpec(128, iv))
        cipher.doFinal(encryptedData).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
    }
}
```